# Merge two objects but maintain inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

So, I have a class named Color, and another called Component.
Currently I create a new ColorComponent like this:

```
ColorComponent = Component.extend({
  init: {
    this.color = new Color();
  }
});
```

But I don't wanna access the color variable by typing things like colorComponent.color.r, I would like to directly access the variables like colorComponent.r.
So I used a merge function to merge the two objects, but that destroys my class inheritance.

```
colorComponent instanceof ColorComponent //true
colorComponent instanceof Color //false
```

The problem is, the Color class comes from a library, so I cannot use my extend function to maintain my inheritance. Is there any way to merge these two classes so that the both codelines above return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, an object can only inherit from one prototype in JavaScript.

And [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is absolutely the correct approach to model this. There is no such thing that is both a `Color` and a `Component`. You might be looking for a `Colored` "class", for things that *have a* color, but you'd use a mixin for that not inheritance either.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if you can even do it. I guess you're right it would be not very clean code, I just wanted it to make simpler for the user backend without too much work.